# Clarification on student expenses - To file the tax for the next year

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction

Clarification on student expenses - To file the tax for the next year.

I have a full time job as well as going back to Grad school as a Part Time Student. Do i need to collect all my bills such as Student Parking, Books, Distance commuting ..  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here that you're talking about deducting your tuition as a below the line deduction as a business expense or similar, then it depends.

Per [1.162-5](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.162-5), if the education:

> - Maintains or improves skills required by the individual in his employment or other trade or business
> - Meets the express requirements of the individual's employer, or the requirements of applicable law or regulations, imposed as a condition
>     to the retention by the individual of an established employment
>     relationship, status, or rate of compensation

Then it qualifies as a legitimate business expense and is deductible.  If not - if you're going to school for a different career, such as someone employed as a waiter but going to school to get a degree in nursing, or someone employed as a teacher getting a law degree - then it's not; you'd have to qualify under one of the other (simpler, but lesser) credits.

Read more on this topic at [Tax topic 513](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc513.html).

Note that the other most commonly applicable deduction - the above the line Tuition and Fees deduction - expired in 2016 and is not applicable (yet?) in 2017, and further would not require most of what you describe as it only counts tuition and fees paid *directly to the institution* and *required as a condition of attendance*, so books, parking, etc. don't count.

Comment: thank you so much !! Explanation is very helpful :) , Though disappointing that i can't deduct all the expenses...